# Input to capture minutes and seconds in the format (mm:ss) in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a simple form for an application in angularjs. I need an input field to recieve time data with only minutes and seconds in the format "mm:ss". Anyone who has worked on this, your assistance would be highly appreciated. I already have created time input for my form. Actually, I am working on project created by other programmer. The model for the time input was initialized as follows:

```
function initDate(date, indexX, indexY){
      if(date != null && date != ''){
        var dateArray = date.split(":");
        var dt = new Date(1970,1,1,dateArray[0],dateArray[1],dateArray[2]);
        vm.modelDate[indexX][indexY] = dt;
      }
}

<input name="inputExTime{{q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId}}{{contTime}}0"
    type="time" class="form-control btn-act btn-act-inputs intime_ex" step="1"
    ng-disabled="disabledfields"
    ng-model="vm.modelDate[0][contTime]"
    min="00:00:00" max="12:59:00"
    ng-change="vm.changeDate(parentIndex,0,contTime);vm.calculateHours(form['inputExTime'+q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId+contTime+0].$modelValue, form['inputExTime'+q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId+contTime+2].$modelValue, form['inputExTime'+q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId+contTime+3], contTime);vm.average();"
    ng-required="$index<vm.numberOfRequiredRows?(q.attributes.required==false?false:isregister):false"
    ng-class="{true: 'inp-f'}[form['inputExTime'+q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId+contTime+0].$invalid]"
    ng-init="vm.modelDate[0][contTime]=null;vm.initArray(''+q.listSubQuestions[contTime].questionId+contTime+0);vm.initDate(q.listSubQuestions[0].listAnswers[contTime].detail, 0, contTime);"
```

/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an `input` element in your form of the time `time`:

```
<input type="time" ng-model="timeModel">
```

The `ng-model` would be a Date object. Otherwise, AngularJS will throw an error.

```js
var app = angular.module('time', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // The order of the params is the following:
  // Year, Month, Day, Time, Minutes, Seconds
  $scope.timeModel = new Date(2017, 10, 13, 10, 30, 0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="time">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Time Model Example using AngularJS</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="time" ng-model="timeModel">
</body>

</html>
```

On the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[time]), you can find more information about this.

Keep Rocking!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I have added a few detail related to the problem so you can share more light on how to achieve the similar result to the snippet you posted.